# XSLT autonumbering multi level but unstructured document

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a number of XML (XHTML, in fact) documents that contain multi-level clauses that I want to auto-number; the trouble is that the documents are unstructured flat lists with the level indicated in a text attribute. Yes, I know, but I can't realistically change them; too many and too big.

A simplified case showing the structure and the labels I would like is:

```
<root>
  <p label="1" class="clause_L1">A</p>
  <p label="1.1" class="clause_L2">B</p>
  <p label="1.2" class="clause_L2">C</p>
  <p label="1.3" class="clause_L2">D</p>
  <p label="2" class="clause_L1">E</p>
  <p label="3" class="clause_L1">F</p>
  <p label="4" class="clause_L1">G</p>
  <p label="4.1" class="clause_L2">H</p>
  <p label="4.1.1" class="clause_L3">I</p>
  <p label="4.1.2" class="clause_L3">J</p>
  <p label="4.2" class="clause_L2">K</p>
  <p label="4.3" class="clause_L2">L</p>
</root>
```

After much hacking around, I've got the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[substring(@class, 1, 6) = 'clause']">
   <xsl:variable name="class" select="@class"/>
   <xsl:variable name="level" select="substring(@class, 9, 1)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="parent" select="preceding-sibling::p[@class = concat('clause_L', $level - 1)][1]"/>
   <xsl:variable name="parentPos" select="count($parent/preceding-sibling::p[substring(@class, 1, 6) = 'clause']) + 1"/>

   <clause>
    <xsl:attribute name="parent">
      <xsl:value-of select="$parent/@label"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="parentPos">
      <xsl:value-of select="$parentPos"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="origLabel">
       <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="label">
       <xsl:number count="p[string($parent) = '' or position() &gt; $parentPos][@class = $class]" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </clause>
</xsl:template>
```

...which gives me the correct numbering for the lowest current level:

```
<clause parent="" parentPos="1" origLabel="1" label="1">A</clause>
<clause parent="1" parentPos="1" origLabel="1.1" label="1">B</clause>
<clause parent="1" parentPos="1" origLabel="1.2" label="2">C</clause>
<clause parent="1" parentPos="1" origLabel="1.3" label="3">D</clause>
<clause parent="" parentPos="1" origLabel="2" label="2">E</clause>
<clause parent="" parentPos="1" origLabel="3" label="3">F</clause>
<clause parent="" parentPos="1" origLabel="4" label="4">G</clause>
<clause parent="4" parentPos="7" origLabel="4.1" label="1">H</clause>
<clause parent="4.1" parentPos="8" origLabel="4.1.1" label="1">I</clause>
<clause parent="4.1" parentPos="8" origLabel="4.1.2" label="2">J</clause>
<clause parent="4" parentPos="7" origLabel="4.2" label="2">K</clause>
<clause parent="4" parentPos="7" origLabel="4.3" label="3">L</clause>
```

First of all, is it possible to generate the higher level numbers for the label within this template, as it seems xsl:number only works in the current context - so I don't know how to get the current next level up counter.

Secondly is there a better way to do this full stop? Bearing in mind I am stuck with the source data format.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, and in a reasonably neat and general way using recursion, so will cope with arbitrary levels.

This could be usefully modified for anyone attempting to create a structured document from a flat one, too.

--- Performance is probably atrocious but this is not a high volume app, so I don't care ;o)

**EDIT**: The performance was actually godawful, so I have updated the answer with a more optimised one; the actual thing causing the performance issue was a bit weird and is commented in the code, I presume it is to do with how the lazy evaluation works. Without the pre-evaluation the full recursive run takes over a minute and a half to run on my data (~400 clauses), and with it it takes 5 seconds. I'm using the XSLT engine in .NET 4. Five seconds sounds a while, but this is just the full app run including generation, download and browser rendering of a PDF final document, I haven't measured the transform alone.

Using source XML as above, XSL is:

```
<xsl:template match="p[substring(@class, 1, 6) = 'clause']">
   <clause>
    <xsl:attribute name="origLabel">
         <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="label">
       <xsl:call-template name="makeLabel">
           <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </clause>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="makeLabel">
   <xsl:param name="node"/>

   <xsl:variable name="class" select="$node/@class"/>
   <xsl:variable name="level" select="substring($class, 9, 1)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="parent" select="$node/preceding-sibling::p[@class = concat('clause_L', $level - 1)][1]"/>
   <xsl:variable name="parentPos" select="count($parent/preceding-sibling::p[substring(@class, 1, 6) = 'clause']) + 1"/>
   <xsl:variable name="myPos" select="count($node/preceding-sibling::p[substring(@class, 1, 6) = 'clause']) + 1"/>
   <xsl:variable name="precPos" select="number($myPos - $parentPos)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="topLevel" select="not($parent)"/>

   <xsl:if test="string($parent) != ''">
       <xsl:call-template name="makeLabel">
           <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$parent"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>

   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$topLevel">
      <xsl:value-of select="count($node/preceding-sibling::p[@class = $class]) + 1" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!--
        It is ABSOLUTELY REQUIRED to pre-evaluate $precPos before the count(); without this the request takes over a minute to run; 
        with it, it takes ~5 seconds.
      -->
      <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="$precPos"/></xsl:comment>
      <!-- -->
      <xsl:value-of select="count($node/preceding-sibling::p[position() &lt; $precPos][@class = $class]) + 1" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>    
   <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Which gives the intended result:

```
<clause origLabel="1" label="1.">A</clause>
<clause origLabel="1.1" label="1.1.">B</clause>
<clause origLabel="1.2" label="1.2.">C</clause>
<clause origLabel="1.3" label="1.3.">D</clause>
<clause origLabel="2" label="2.">E</clause>
<clause origLabel="3" label="3.">F</clause>
<clause origLabel="4" label="4.">G</clause>
<clause origLabel="4.1" label="4.1.">H</clause>
<clause origLabel="4.1.1" label="4.1.1.">I</clause>
<clause origLabel="4.1.2" label="4.1.2.">J</clause>
<clause origLabel="4.2" label="4.2.">K</clause>
<clause origLabel="4.3" label="4.3.">L</clause>
```